# send parameter in to shell command

Tags: ubuntu, sms, gsm

I'm newbie to linux so please to help me.
I am using ModemManager on Ubuntu 18.04LTS (Srv1) with GSM modem connected. My task is when some trigger action on server monitor, zabbix will run a script ssh to Srv1 and send SMS to administrator. Here is code:

```
#!/bin/bash
v1=$1
v2=$2
count=$( cat countmess)
count=$((count+1))
//textt="$v1 have issue $v2"
sshpass -p "12345678" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no monitor@192.168.29.190 sudo mmcli -m 1 --messaging-create-sms="text='$(v1) have issue $(v2)',number='+8412345678'"
sshpass -p "12345678" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no monitor@192.168.29.190 sudo mmcli -s $count --send exit
rm -f countmess
echo "$count" >> countmess
exit
```

---

call: `./sms_script.sh abc check`
sh file receive 2 arguments v1 as hostname(abc) and v2 as trigger name(check). Then it reads a counter variable from "countmess" file. The problem here is the command:

```
> sudo mmcli -m 1 --messaging-create-sms="text='$(v1) have issue $(v2)',number='+8412345678'"
```

it returns error:

> error: cannot parse properties string: 'Unexpected content (have issue check,number=+8412345678) after value'

please show me the way to fix it.
sorry for my bad  english

Answer (score 0):

In your script call v1 and v2 Like this:

`sudo mmcli -m 1 --messaging-create-sms="text='$v1 have issue $v2',number='+8412345678'"`